# 'Series' object has no attribute 'flatten' when I use y.flatten()

Tags: python

I am stuck here since last night everything was working just fine and now this.

May I know what the bug is?

Its just frustrating.

I am trying to implement sigmoid function for a give data set.

I want to change its orientation basically for theat I have used y.flatten which is giving me above mentioned error.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Please show us your code and explain your issue more detailed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`flatten` is a method of `np.array` not of `pd.Series`.

Try

```
y.values.flatten()
```

Comment: I never created a pd.series actually its an output of regression. It was an array earlier. I don't know why it has turned into a pd.series. Is there a way to make it an array? Because I have to use it to implement MSE. Thanks

Comment: yes, via the values property. `y.values` contains the values of a `Series` and is of type `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: If you provide the relevant code, people could give you hints about why's and even can point you to alternatives of things you could do better even if you didn't address them directly. But if you only talk _about_ things you do _somehow_ and basically post only an error message, people have to guess what you perhaps might mean/do/know/plan/discover/want...., which is inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have convert these series y_test and y_pred to numpy array to using the flatten function, i got the same problem but fixed it using the following fix:

1) Use y_test.shape. To find out the shape of your dataframe series i.e. in your case y_test and y_pred.

2) Use the number of rows and columns found out by shape to reshape this data frame column or series to a Numpy array. Because flatten is a function of Numpy array.

3) Then use your flatten function, i would work.

The code is given below. 1. Step one: `test.shape` 2. Step two (reshape) : `test = test.values.reshape(1,4069)` 3. `df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': test.flatten(), 'Predicted': pred.flatten()})`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this is because flatten is a method of NumPy array and not of pandas Series. So you can convert that pandas series to NumPy array to use the flatten method.
You can convert a pandas Series to a NumPy array by using `to_numpy()` method of Series :

```
y.to_numpy()  # it will return the Numpy array on which we can use flatten
```